# getTimeStamp() not found in runnable jar, but is found otherwise

Tags: java, exception, jar

I've have trouble deploying an application that runs fine within eclipse, but generates the following error when creating a runnable jar (using the option: **extract required libraries into generated JAR**):

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getTimeStamp()J)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
```

I'm using log4j-1.2.16.jar and it's included in the generated jar.

I'm not sure where to troubleshoot, I've tried to find other (older) instances of org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent in other jars that are included, but so far I did not find any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It says, that there is not method *org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getTimeStamp()*
Find again your classes, that are on class path and you should find class *org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent* twice. One with method one without method.

Comment: Thanks! I rechecked and noticed that I included another java project. That java project had an older log4j.jar file that ended up in my runnable jar!

Comment: for me, it meant I had both log4j-1.2.14 and log4j-1.2.16 [16 has the getTimeStamp method]

Comment: In my case , I **down-graded** the **java** version of **tomcat** from **JDK 1.6.0.25** to **jre6** .

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using log4j-1.2.16.jar and it's included in the generated jar.

Java class loaders are not designed to deal with a Jar inside a Jar.  It is possible to put the *resources* (classes etc.) of a Jar into another Jar (I think using a tool called 'FatJar' in Eclipse), but that might break the EULA.

The usual way to include a Jar on the run-time class path of an application is to add a manifest file that specifies a relative path to the Jar.

Comment: Yes, I know, but in this case it was simply using the wrong jar file as it was included twice. Unfortunately you do not get a warning when that happens in your project when generating the jar.

Comment: @Roalt:  Glad you got it sorted. :)